# How to Solve "LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.5/ffi_c" Running Ruby on Rails with WSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to get a (private) Ruby on Rails application up and running on my Windows machine using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I was able to run `bundle install` without any errors but now when I run `rails apartment:create` I get the error:

LoadError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/myDirectory/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi_c.so

Complete error is below.

I tried reinstalling ruby with `rvm get head` and `rvm reinstall 2.5.7`, reinstalling ffi with `gem uninstall ffi` and `gem install ffi -v 1.11.1`, and creating a symbolic link with `ln -s libffi.so.8 libffi.so.1.8`, but get the same result.

I see the referenced file is there:
[image]

Anything else I can try?

```
me@LAPTOP-xyz:/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master$ rails apartment:create
rails aborted!
LoadError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi_c.so
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.5/ffi_c
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/ffi-1.11.1/lib/ffi.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:22:in `block in perform'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.7/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/mnt/c/Users/me/Documents/app/Application/master/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your current setup is, but I recently ran into a similar issue as this error with WSL.

For *me*, I believe the issued was when I had installed `ffmpeg` through Homebrew for Linux. In doing `brew install ffmpeg`, I believe it added a `brew install ffi` as a result of its dependencies, causing *something* on my system to change with regard to FFI.

After re-installing (through `rbenv`) a couple of times to no-avail, I finally did a `brew uninstall ffi --ignore-dependencies` and then did another `rbenv install 2.7.4`.

After this, I was successfully able to `gem install llhttp-ffi -v 0.4.0` whereas I wasn't able to before because of the same error message you are receiving.

Apologies for not having any other specifics other than having the same error as you. Hope you get pointed in the right direction.